# Problema entre REQUIRED y SUMBIT en un formulario html-

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, formularios

Hola gente como andan?,

Estoy terminando de hacer un formulario de a pasos, donde hay inputs/labels/select pero cuando hago click en el boton para que vaya del paso 1 al paso 2, los required de los inputs no me los estaria tomando. No sabria el motivo. En caso de tener que agregar un javascript como seria? Estuve todo el dia de hoy buscando info e intentado de encontrar el error pero no tuve solucion. Les comparto mi HTML para que lo miren y me corrijan! Si necesitan que les explique algo de lo que hice o necesitan el css me avisan. Como decia antes, ya tengo la cabeza quemada y ya no se por donde ir. Gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleNuevoProyecto.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <title>Base de Datos en CyT -- UTN FRBA</title>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
        var opacity;

        $(".next").click(function() {

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //Add Class Active
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                step: function(now) {
                    // for making fielset appear animation
                    opacity = 1 - now;

                    current_fs.css({
                        'display': 'none',
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                    next_fs.css({
                        'opacity': opacity
                    });
                },
                duration: 600
            });
        });

        $(".previous").click(function() {

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

            //Remove class active
            $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

            //show the previous fieldset
            previous_fs.show();

            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, {
                step: function(now) {
                    // for making fielset appear animation
                    opacity = 1 - now;

                    current_fs.css({
                        'display': 'none',
                        'position': 'relative'
                    });
                    previous_fs.css({
                        'opacity': opacity
                    });
                },
                duration: 600
            });
        });

        $('.radio-group .radio').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        $(".submit").click(function() {
            return false;
        })

    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99e675b6e.js"></script>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-image: url('images/fondoNavbar.jpeg')">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="index.php">Base de Datos</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">test</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-1" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="color: #FFF;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="index.php"><i class="bi bi-house-door-fill"></i> Inicio <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="verProyectos.php" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-kanban"></i>
                        Proyectos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="verProyectos.php" style="color: white;">Ver todos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="verInformesProyectos.php" style="color: white;">Ver
                            Informes</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-people"></i>
                        Recursos Humanos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Todos los recursos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Asignados a Proyectos</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Asignados a Becas</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i
                            class="bi bi-cash-coin"></i>
                        Presupuesto
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Asignar Presupuesto</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-book"></i>
                        Publicaciones
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Ver Publicaciones</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-calendar"></i>
                        Eventos
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;">Ver Eventos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i> Configuración <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse order-3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto testColor">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                        Perfil
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu clearLeft" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        style="background-image: url('images/fondoDropdown.jpeg')">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="color: white;"><i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
                            Ajustes</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="cerrarSesion.php" style="color: white;"><i
                                class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>
                            Salir</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="nuevoProyecto">
        <!-- MultiStep Form -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mt-0">
                <div class="col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-6 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
                    <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3">
                        <h1><strong>Nuevo proyecto</strong></h1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 mx-0">
                                <!-- progressbar -->
                                <ul id="progressbar">
                                    <li class="active" id="proyecto"><strong>Datos del proyecto</strong></li>
                                    <li id="proyectoDos"><strong>Presupuesto</strong></li>
                                    <li id="general"><strong>General</strong></li>
                                    <li id="confirm"><strong>Finish</strong></li>
                                </ul> <!-- fieldsets -->
                                <form id="msform" name="formNuevoProyecto" action="cargarProyecto.php"
                                    onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-card">
                                            <h2 class="fs-title">Datos del proyecto</h2> <input type="text"
                                                name="nombreProyecto" placeholder="Nombre del proyecto" required>
                                            <input type="text" name="nombreAbreviadoProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Nombre Abreviado del proyecto" required> <input type="text"
                                                name="palabrasClaveProyecto" placeholder="Palabras Clave" />
                                            <select class="list-dt" id="month" name="expmonth">
                                                <option selected>Tipo de Proyecto</option>
                                                <option>PID para Equipos de Trabajo Consolidado (PID TC) Tipo A
                                                </option>
                                                <option>PID para Equipos de Trabajo Consolidado (PID TC) Tipo B
                                                </option>
                                                <option>PID para Equipos de Trabajo en Consolidación (PID EC) Tipo A
                                                </option>
                                                <option>PID para Equipos de Trabajo en Consolidación (PID EC) Tipo B
                                                </option>
                                                <option>PID Primer Proyecto (PID PP) Tipo A</option>
                                                <option>PID Primer Proyecto (PID PP) Tipo B</option>
                                                <option>PID Tecnología Educativa y Enseñanza de la Ingeniería (PIDA
                                                    TEEI) Tipo A</option>
                                                <option>PID Tecnología Educativa y Enseñanza de la Ingeniería (PIDA
                                                    TEEI) Tipo B</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <p class="espacio"></p>
                                            <select class="list-dt" id="month" name="expmonth">
                                                <option selected>Dependencia principal</option>
                                                <optgroup label="Departamentos">
                                                    <option>Departamento de Ciencias Básicas (UDB)</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Civil</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Eléctrica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Electrónica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento de Ingeniería Industrial</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Mecánica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Naval</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Química</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería en Sistemas de Información
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Textil</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Cultura e Idiomas</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Física</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Legislación y Economía</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Matemática</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Química</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Centros">
                                                    <option>Centro de Procesamiento de Señales e Imágenes (CPSI)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Centro de Investigación e Innovación Educativa (CIIE)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Centro de Tecnologías Químicas (CTQ)</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Grupos">
                                                    <option>Grupo de Investigación y Desarrollo en BIO Ingeniería
                                                        (GIBIO)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Grupo de Inteligencia Artificial y Robótica (GIAR)
                                                    </option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                            <p class="espacio"></p><input type="text" name="otrasDependenciasProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Otras Dependencias" /><label><strong>Dependencias
                                                    adicionales</strong>
                                            </label><select class="list-dtt" id="month" name="expmonth" multiple>
                                                <optgroup label="Departamentos">
                                                    <option>Departamento de Ciencias Básicas (UDB)</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Civil</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Eléctrica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Electrónica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento de Ingeniería Industrial</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Mecánica</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Naval</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Química</option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería en Sistemas de Información
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Departamento Ingeniería Textil</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Cultura e Idiomas</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Física</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Legislación y Economía</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Matemática</option>
                                                    <option>UDB - Química</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Centros">
                                                    <option>Centro de Procesamiento de Señales e Imágenes (CPSI)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Centro de Investigación e Innovación Educativa (CIIE)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Centro de Tecnologías Químicas (CTQ)</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Grupos">
                                                    <option>Grupo de Investigación y Desarrollo en BIO Ingeniería
                                                        (GIBIO)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option>Grupo de Inteligencia Artificial y Robótica (GIAR)
                                                    </option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                            <p class="espacio"></p><input type="text"
                                                name="primerDependenciaExternaProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Primera Dependencia Externa" /><input type="text"
                                                name="segundaDependenciaExternaProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Segunda Dependencia Externa" /><input type="text"
                                                name="tercerDependenciaExternaProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Tercera Dependencia Externa" />
                                            <input type="text" name="codigoFRBAProyecto" placeholder="Codigo FRBA"
                                                required><input type="text" name="codigoUTNProyecto"
                                                placeholder="Codigo UTN" require><select class="list-dt" id="month"
                                                name="expmonth" required>
                                                <option selected>Programa</option>
                                                <option>Análisis De Señales, Modelados Y Simulación</option>
                                                <option>Aplicaciones Mecánicas Y Mecatrónica</option>
                                                <option>Electrónica, Computación Y Comunicaciones</option>
                                                <option>Energía</option>
                                                <option>Estructuras Y Construcciones Civiles</option>
                                                <option>Ingeniería Clínica Y Bioingeniería</option>
                                                <option>Ingeniería De Procesos, Biotecnología Y Tecnología De
                                                    Alimentos
                                                </option>
                                                <option>Materiales</option>
                                                <option>Medio Ambiente, Contingencias Y Desarrollo Sustentable
                                                </option>
                                                <option>Sistemas De Información E Informática</option>
                                                <option>Tecnología Educativa Y Enseñanza De La Ingeniería</option>
                                                <option>Tecnologías De Las Organizaciones</option>
                                                <option>Transportes Y Vías De Comunicación</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <p class="espacio"></p>
                                            <select class="list-dt" id="month" name="expmonth" require>
                                                <option selected>Tipo de Actividad</option>
                                                <option>Desarrollo Experimental</option>
                                                <option>Investigación Aplicada</option>
                                                <option>Investigación Básica</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div> <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button"
                                            value="Siguiente" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-card">
                                            <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Information</h2> <input type="text"
                                                name="fname" placeholder="First Name" /> <input type="text" name="lname"
                                                placeholder="Last Name" /> <input type="text" name="phno"
                                                placeholder="Contact No." /> <input type="text" name="phno_2"
                                                placeholder="Alternate Contact No." />
                                        </div> <input type="button" name="previous"
                                            class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" /> <input
                                            type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-card">
                                            <h2 class="fs-title">Payment Information</h2>
                                            <div class="radio-group">
                                                <div class='radio' data-value="credit"><img
                                                        src="https://i.imgur.com/XzOzVHZ.jpg" width="200px"
                                                        height="100px"></div>
                                                <div class='radio' data-value="paypal"><img
                                                        src="https://i.imgur.com/jXjwZlj.jpg" width="200px"
                                                        height="100px"></div> <br>
                                            </div> <label class="pay">Card Holder Name*</label> <input type="text"
                                                name="holdername" placeholder="" />
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-9"> <label class="pay">Card Number*</label> <input
                                                        type="text" name="cardno" placeholder="" /> </div>
                                                <div class="col-3"> <label class="pay">CVC*</label> <input
                                                        type="password" name="cvcpwd" placeholder="***" /> </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-3"> <label class="pay">Expiry Date*</label> </div>
                                                <div class="col-9"> <select class="list-dt" id="month" name="expmonth">
                                                        <option selected>Month</option>
                                                        <option>January</option>
                                                        <option>February</option>
                                                        <option>March</option>
                                                        <option>April</option>
                                                        <option>May</option>
                                                        <option>June</option>
                                                        <option>July</option>
                                                        <option>August</option>
                                                        <option>September</option>
                                                        <option>October</option>
                                                        <option>November</option>
                                                        <option>December</option>
                                                    </select> <select class="list-dt" id="year" name="expyear">
                                                        <option selected>Year</option>
                                                    </select> </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><input type="button" name="previous"
                                            class="previous action-button-previous" value="Previous" /> <input
                                            type="button" name="make_payment" class="next action-button"
                                            value="Confirm" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-card">
                                            <h2 class="fs-title text-center">Success !</h2> <br><br>
                                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-3"> <img
                                                        src="https://img.icons8.com/color/96/000000/ok--v2.png"
                                                        class="fit-image"> </div>
                                            </div> <br><br>
                                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-7 text-center">
                                                    <h5>You Have Successfully Signed Up</h5>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: El evento clic de los botones se dispara antes del evento `submit` del formulario y no permite que se analice si los campos requeridos fueron llenados correctamente. Tienes dos opciones: a) Realizar validación de campos manualmente en cada clic de los botones b) Cada sección debe ser un formulario independiente y, al finalizar, tratar de enviar todos los formularios como uno solo; no es tan complicado si se procesa con petición AJAX.

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido reportada automáticamente por el sistema debido a su extensión. No necesitas tomar ninguna medida en el momento, pero lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] e intenta que tus futuras preguntas no sean tan extensas.